# Como fazer background "personalizado" para uma palavra? (como mostra a imagem)

Tags: jquery, html, css, css3

Como fazer esse tipo de efeito de background, conforme a imagem abaixo? Se possível usando CSS.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero que ele fique como na imagem. Fiz com o text-shadow (http://jsfiddle.net/9N94B/) mas num ficou legal eu acho.

Comment: dei minha resposta mas pelo que vi na sua edição, é você já sabia o caminho. É isso mesmo. Agora você tem que modelar o estilo para ficar nas cores e proporções desejadas!

Comment: O máximo que consegui foi fazer isto: http://jsfiddle.net/dieegov/9N94B/2/ (tive que usar uma atributo, para poder recupera-lo no css)

Comment: @JeffesonAlison, acredito que use uma imagem (GIF ou PNG) no background com repetição em x para chegar nesse resultado, se possível, poderia postar o link de onde esse texto foi retirado?

Comment: Ok @DiegoVieira, ja pensei nisso. Mas se usar uma imagem tem alguns lugares que num vai ficar legal tipo, quando tem o acento, pode notar que a background "sobe". Ainda não esta disponível o link, estou montando o layout por enquanto. Curti o jeito que fez com o shadow no comentario anterior.

Comment: Já tentou combinar vários sombreamentos aumentando o *blur* gradualmente? Exemplo: `text-shadow: 0 0 5px #BAD042, 0 0 10px #BAD042, 0 0 15px #BAD042, 0 0 20px #BAD042, 0 0 25px #BAD042, 0 0 30px #BAD042;` Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9N94B/5/

Answer (score 1):

Use `CSS3 Text Shadow`:

```
<style>
.sombra {
    text-shadow: 1px 2px 3px #666;
}
</style>
<p class=sombra>Teste</p>
```